# Django Models и Form

Tags: django

Я новичок У меня такой проект суть проекта проводить "Проводить опрос" участник должен регистрироваться на сайте и должен отвечать на вопросы я создал 3 модела 1й для регистрации 2ой там хранится вопросы а на 3й там должен хранятся ответы которые кто отвечал на вопросы  `models.py`

```
class User(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    specialite = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname
class Stimul_slov(models.Model):
    stimulus = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % ( self.stimulus)

class Otvet(models.Model):
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stimul = models.ForeignKey(Stimul_slov, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return  "%s: %s ----> %s" % (self.user ,self.stimul, self.answer)
```

для регистрации новый пользователя я использовал форм `form.py`

```
from django import forms 
from .models import *

class User(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "fullname",
            "age",
            "email",
            "specialite",
            "language",

        ]
```

у меня пока регистрация готова  `views.py`

```
def startapp(request): 
    context ={}
    form = User(request.POST) 
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return test(request)

    else:
        return render(request, "index.html", context ) 

def test(request):

        return render(request, 'test.html',)
```

Пожалуйста дайте мне ваше драгоценный советы как мне реализовать сохранить ответы на бд я сам очень долго искал но похоже на этого не нашел у меня три связка для  реализации у меня знание чуть чуть не хватает

Answer (score 1):

Во первых тебе наверное лучше использовать стандартную модель для `user` от `django`. Вообще лучше всегда ее юзать, а если не хватает полей в стандартной модели, то через `One-To-One` расширить её. Это позволит избежать ошибок на начальном этапе. 
Что касается сохранения ответов, нужно создать форму для сохранения ответов, так же как это сделано с пользователем. Т.к. у тебя ответы связаны с вопросами один ко многим, ты можешь выводить вопрос, а под ней форму для ответов, относящиеся к этому вопросу, и передавать `id`, чтобы явно указать к какому вопросу относится данный ответ.

Comment: сейчас попробую так делать спасибо за ответ ))

Comment: как вы сказали я так и делал но у меня ещё возникло ещё один проблема `class OtvetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Otvet
        fields = ('answer','user','stimul')
        user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Profil.objects.all())
        stimul = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Otvet.objects.all())`

Comment: как мне передавать `id` пожалуйста подскажите

Comment: Если ты используешь django шаблоны, то у тебя есть возможность передавать в шаблон переменные используя контекст. https://youtu.be/h05UEays2KI вот неплохой урок на эту тему. Собстеноо ты можешь во вьюхе доставать объект отрисовываемого запроса, и передавать объект через кнтекст в шаблон, а в шаблоне у тебя уже будет id